# Getting NullReferenceException in IIS7 integrated mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, iis-7, structuremap

I've an application runing .NET 4.0 with

- MVC 3.0
- Microsoft ServiceLocator 1.0
- StructureMap 2.6.2
- StructureMap Adapter 1.1.0.2
- NHibernate 3.1.0.4000
- Log4Net 1.2.10

The application is running well in development server, IIS6 and IIS7 classic mode.
Running the same application in IIS7 integrated mode gives after Global.asax Application_Start an NullReferenceException.

The stacktrace is:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error) +1116
System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb) +89
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +189
```

The attached debugger does not break at exception. But the page shows the yellow page of death.

Any idea where I can look or hook to fix the error?

Comment: Are you loading HttpModules or HttpHandlers? IIS6, IIS7 Classic and Cassini use the same setting whereas IIS7 Integrated differs in the way you have to setup an HttpHandler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821934/error-when-deploying-asp-net-mvc-nhibernate-app-to-iis7

Comment: Andreas, I've only a global.asax and no other modules or handler. NHibernate is initialized in Application_Start. I will try the fix given in your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Error when deploying ASP.NET MVC NHibernate app to IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821934/error-when-deploying-asp-net-mvc-nhibernate-app-to-iis7)  and a lot other [posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=nhibernate+iis7+integrated+mode) it is not supported to initialized **NHibernate** in **Application_Start** anymore if application is running in integrated mode. I found no real reason for that behavior. May be that Darins answer is the reason, but I found no access to HttpContext.Current in NHibernate initialization code.

The workarounds are:

- [use a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2074968/asp-net-mvc-application-when-deployed-to-iis-7-in-integrated-mode-using-nhibernat) for initialization of nhibernate
- initialize nhibernate in Application_BeginRequest but assert that it is initialized only once

Answer (score 1):

When running in integrated mode, objects such as the HttpContext, Request, Response, Session, ... are not available in `Application_Start`. So make sure none of your code tries to ever access them in this method.

Comment: Just to clarify what Darin is saying, `Application_Start` was always intended to be a request-agnostic startup method, and shouldn't be used to access the current request. **But** in Classic mode (and how it runs in IIS < 7), the application is initialised with the first request - this is why `HttpContext.Current` is available. In IIS7, the move to decouple the request initialisation away from the application startup has resulted in `HttpContext.Current` becoming unavailable again... this was how it was originally intended to work.

Comment: Matthew, what is the intented way for startup initializsation. IHttpApplication.Init? Is it assert that init is only called once?